# showing different radio buttons when choosing specific button

Tags: javascript, html

I  am trying to make radio buttons where person chose options and different options appear for him/her to chose from. my code is :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
      if($(this).attr('id') == 'wanted') {
        $('.sec-row').show();           
      }

      else {
        $('.sec-row').hide();   
      }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="add_property" method="post" action="#">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="first-row form-group">
            <label for="">Purpose</label>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle ml-5">
                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                    <input type="radio" name="options1" id="forSale" autocomplete="off"> For Sale
                </label>
                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                    <input type="radio" name="options1" id="rent" autocomplete="off"> Rent
                </label>
                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                    <input type="radio" name="options1" id="wanted" autocomplete="off"> Wanted
                </label>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /.first_row -->
        <div class="sec-row form-group ml-3" style="display:none">
            <label for="">Wanted For</label>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                    <input type="radio" name="options2" id="wf-buy" autocomplete="off"> Buy
                </label>
                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                    <input type="radio" name="options2" id="wf-rent" autocomplete="off"> Rent
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third-row form-group">
            <label for="">Property Type</label>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                    <input type="radio" name="options3" id="homes" autocomplete="off">Homes
                </label>
                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                    <input type="radio" name="options3" id="plots" autocomplete="off">Plots
                </label>
                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                    <input type="radio" name="options3" id="commercial" autocomplete="off">commercial
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

but the issue is I am not able to get active value when selecting certain radio button if I use data-toggle="buttons" in divs it works but js doesn't work that way. I need to make 2 or more lines of different radio buttons where they appear when some specific button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use common name in radio button and pass value attribute too.

```
<div class="first-row form-group">
    <label for="">Purpose</label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle ml-5">
        <label class="btn bg-olive">
            <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="forSale" id="forSale" autocomplete="off"> For Sale
        </label>
        <label class="btn bg-olive">
            <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="rent" id="rent" autocomplete="off"> Rent
        </label>
        <label class="btn bg-olive">
             <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="wanted" id="wanted" autocomplete="off"> Wanted
        </label>
     </div>
 </div>




$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
      var value = $("input[name='purpose']:checked").val();
      if(value == 'wanted') {
        $('.sec-row').show();           
      }
      else {
        $('.sec-row').hide();   
      }
  });

});
```

Comment: it works for sec-row those two can be seen selected and show() and hide() working well but can it be checked for every radio button i click? so user know which options hes been clicking and going down? thanks btw

Comment: i am using this answer so i will upvote this i removed the btn-group-toggle then it worked. its not complete yet as something else need to add but its what i got close to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form role="form" id="add_property" method="post" action="#">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="first-row form-group">
                            <label for="">Purpose</label>
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle ml-5">
                                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options1" id="forSale" autocomplete="off"> For Sale
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options1" id="rent" autocomplete="off"> Rent
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options1" id="wanted" autocomplete="off"> Wanted
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- /.first_row -->
                        <div class="sec-row form-group ml-3" style="display:none">
                            <label for="">Wanted For</label>
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options4" id="wf-buy" autocomplete="off"> Buy
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options5" id="wf-rent" autocomplete="off"> Rent
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="third-row form-group">
                            <label for="">Property Type</label>
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
                                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options6" id="homes" autocomplete="off">Homes
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options7" id="plots" autocomplete="off">Plots
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn bg-olive">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options8" id="commercial" autocomplete="off">commercial
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        var radio_value=$(this).attr('id');

      if(radio_value == 'wanted') {
        $('.sec-row').show();           
      }else {
        $('.sec-row').hide();   
      }
  });

});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are used for multiple questions. If clicked any radio button in second row or third row, the second row will hide.

Comment: its working same as what i was using before i need radio buttons to show active where i click and yes 2nd row hide when clicked on third.

Comment: you can add same name of all radio button like that <input type="radio" name="options1" id="forSale" autocomplete="off"> For Sale,<input type="radio" name="options1" id="rent" autocomplete="off"> Rent,<input type="radio" name="options1" id="wanted" autocomplete="off"> Wanted

Comment: i was naming them separate that was mistake, thanks for telling. but its not making it selected the first row and 2nd row always disapear when i click 3rd one only way its staying active when i use data-toggle but that makes js not working if i use it.

Comment: its still not working as i said 2nd div goes hidden again when 3rd is selected

Comment: i tried that didn't work i had to remove the btn-group-toggle class to make it  for now.

Comment: You will remove btn-group-toggle in every div?

Comment: yes thats what i did. then it let all of the answers here worked. but it did made them look not good.